# How do I get access to system32?

Tags: file-permissions

I have been trying to delete a file in "System32" because all it does is a useless popup.

However, whenever I try to delete the file, it says that I need permissions from TrustedInstaller.

**How do I get permissions to that file?**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to delete **any** file in your file system. Some are system files and may cause your Windows to error if missing. Windows does not allow you to delete these.

Note that some files that you do have permissions to delete, may cause your system to become unstable. In general, you should be really careful with deleting files inside `Windows` folder. Do your research, ask people about your specific file and whether it's safe to delete it (or know the consequences). If you decide to, be sure to make a backup of your system prior to any changes.

Comment: It's the file that keeps popping 'Your windows is not genuine'. It's WGATray.exe

Comment: @Meraj99: [Google](https://www.google.ca/search?q=WGA.exe) is your friend. Found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi71Rk6CyAg) and [this](http://failedexe.com/2006/06/07/how-to-disabling-windows-genuine-advantage-wgatrayexe/).